# babel transpile `let` into `var`, how runtime know it should depend on block scope

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs, var, let

Here babel transpile `let` into `var`, how the javascript runtime know it should depend on block scope.

code:

```js
for(let  i=10; i<11; i++){
  console.log(12);
}
```

babel compiles it into:

```js
"use strict";

for (var i = 10; i < 11; i++) {
  console.log(12);
}
```

I used the `try it out` and choose `es2015` on babel homepage.

Comment: _"how the javascript runtime know it should depend on block scope?"_ It doesn't, because it does not need to. Babel is smart enough to tell if you really need block scope or not. In this case, it knew that it did not matter because you never use `i`, so it just replaced it with `var`. But in a case that really matters, it will produce a very different code. Try pasting `for(let  i=0; i<10; i++){ setTimeout(() => console.log(i), 10); }` for example

Answer (score 3):

The compiler will know if the function should be wrapped in another function call to create it's own closure. In your case it doesn't matter so the compiler knows another function call is unnecessary.